# Which values should be put in quotation marks and which not in jQuery's animation

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I was wondering in which cases one should put the values of an animation in quotation marks.

[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)'s site doesn't really explains when. I figured it would be when you are giving a unit value: for instance `"52px"` or `"1em"` whereas opacity is unit-less (`0.9`) I don't know what to do with things such as `borderStyle`, `backgroundColor`, `boxShadow`, `backgroundImage` though and I can't seem to find any examples. Any help and guidelines would be appreciated!

Comment: I think any value except number/digit must be kept in quotations. The numbers with units must be in quotations as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short answer

You should always be good when you put the values in quotation marks, except with booleans (`true` or `false`).

## Long answer

It does not matter what the value will be used for. *"opacity, borderStyle, backgroundColor"*, they don't matter. It's about the *type* of data that you want to pass.

When you put the value in quotation marks, you pass it as a string, when jQuery reads the value it will analize the string and interprit the value. For instance when you want a width in percentage, you pass `{width:"10%"}`, jQuery will see the percentage sign and use it as such.

With the percentage example, you can not pass it without quotation marks, because the `%`-sign does stuff in your script, so simply passing `{width:10%}` will result in a TypeError. Same with `"10px"`, passing `10px` would result in an error, because JavaScript will try to interprit `px` as a variable name if it is not in quotation marks.

So actually the only time when you can leave the quotation marks away is with values that *mean the same thing* when they are not a string, for instance numbers or booleans.